# What's the Access VBA code I can write to select OK when Microsoft Office 10 security box appears?

Tags: ms-access

***What code can I write to select OK when this image appears?***
I'm trying to get Access VBA to fill my PDF with data.  As I was testing the code to be sure the PDF will appear & tab twice to get to the first line for data input, the following box appeared:

[image: Microsoft Office message]

This is the code:

```
FollowHyperlink "C:/Users/Dexter/CA_AgreementForm.pdf"
    
    Sleep 1000 ' wait for PDF to load
    
    ' send 2 TAB keys
    For X = 1 To 2
        SendKeys "{TAB}", True
        Sleep 200
    End If
```

Because my file was from a government website, I did the following in hopes of preventing the Microsoft Office security message from appearing:

Gpedit.msc
User Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, and Attachment Manager:
clicked “Do not preserve zone information in file attachments” Policy to open its property.

Regedit
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Attachments
I clicked DWORD (32-bit) Value, then named it "ScanWithAntiVirus" and then disabled the Attachment Manager by double-clicking "ScanWithAntivirus" and changed its value data to 1 and clicked OK

THIS DIDN'T WORK AT ALL! Please help me solve this problem. Thank you

Comment: AFAIK, just opening a PDF via hyperlink is not going to allow you to manipulate that PDF.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fill a PDF Form from MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876561/fill-a-pdf-form-from-ms-access)