# How many pages can a report make?

Tags: ms-access

I cannot find any helpful article online. I'd like to know what the maximum amount of pages one can have in an access report. I'm currently on page 3 and I cannot get the footer to move down anymore.

I found one answer at [DataBaseZone.com](http://www.databasezone.com/techdocs/acclimit.html) but I am unable to add any mroe fields because there isn't any space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you found is correct. A report's detail section has a maximum height of 31680 twips, or 22 inches.

A report can also contain a report header, a page header, a report footer, and a page footer. All these have the same maximum size, and these sizes can be added to that of the main report.

Continuous reports (that repeat for every row in the table) have this limit per row, and don't have an absolute limit.

It seems unlikely (and a little horrific) that you've filled all that space with controls, and still lack space, because that's a LOT of space. Be sure to use the properties pane to set the height of the detail section to the full 22 inches.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Not what I was hopnig for but nonetheless I appreciate it... I'm creating an electronic form of a 16 page report. Hideous? ...Yes.

Comment: Note that, if you really want to create large things, you can fill in PDF forms with Access VBA to overcome this limit (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362014/fill-in-a-pdf-form-from-vba-ms-access) for the main points). You can also use a Word document and content controls, but that might be slightly more difficult (I really don't like content controls). Both offer better design tools to create a good-looking report.

Comment: Kudos to you Erik. Thanks for that. I'll try separating them first and using a macro to print multiple reports. It's simple enough to do. If I don't get the desired result I'll try VBA.